# Empty rust file creates massive WASM build

Tags: rust, build, webassembly

Building the following rust file is producing a binary of 720KB.

I would expect a virtually empty build, what am I missing here? Is the full core libary getting included somehow?

Here's the code

```
#![no_std]
#[panic_handler]
fn handle_panic(_: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    unreachable!()
}
```

And the `cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "wasm_test"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[profile.release]
opt-level = 's'
lto = true
```

And the command I'm using to build:

```bash
cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `strip = true` or `strip = "debuginfo"` in `[profile.release]`?

Comment: Oh, and `cargo build` uses the `dev` profile by default, not `release`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out I had two problems:

1. I was building this as a crate in a workspace, and that apparently ignores crate specific profiles
2. When i copied the crate out to mess around with it and isolate the problem, i was forgetting to add the `--release` flag, thanks @isaactfa.

In other cases i have received this warning.

```
warning: profiles for the non root package will be ignored, specify profiles at the workspace root:
```

for some reason I wasn't getting it when doing the workspace builds.

I've added the crate to the workspace `exclude` list and am building it seperately, and its compiling to a far more appropriate **411 bytes**, down from **727151 bytes**.